# Error while parsing .xlsx with apache poi

Tags: java, android, excel, parsing, apache-poi

I'm trying to parse .xlsx file, but all the time I get the same error:

```
> 20762-20762/com.epon E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions', referenced from method org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.commit
10-21 02:09:25.792  20762-20762/com.epon E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
            at com.epon.MainActivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The sample of my code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath(), "Base.xlsx");


FileInputStream file1 = null;
try {
    file1 = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Workbook workbook = null;
try {
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I had added jars:

```
dependencies {       
compile files('/libs/poi-3.9-20121203.jar')
compile files('/libs/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar')
compile files('/libs/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar')
compile files('/libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar')
```

}

I've read all solutions on stackoverflow,but it doesn't work.

I'm using Android Studio 0.3.0

Comment: It looks like you're somehow missing `xmlbeans` - are you sure you have correctly included the jar for *both* compile and runtime?

Comment: @Gagravarr Not sure about runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a verify error, you should also read carefully the warnings preceeding the error itself. It sometimes gives indication about why the error occured.

For instance, in your exception trace, we can see that the Dalvik can't load a class, but you seem to include it.

Read the warning above that error, they might to help to understand why this class couldn't be loaded, maybe it's super class is missing, or it conflict with something, etc..